# Default value Nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, spring-boot, express, controller

In Spring Boot, in my controller method, I can check and assign default value like below in my controller method.

Instead of checking for `if(query){}`. In case the user doesn't call the endpoint with one of the NOT required parameters, how can I assign default values in express route like Spring boot.

```
router.get('/products', ProductController.getAllProducts);

//...
static async getAllProducts(req, res, next)
```

```java
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getAll(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestParam(name = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "1") @Min(1) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(name = "limit", required = false, defaultValue ="20") Integer limit,
            @RequestParam(name = "description_length", required = false, defaultValue = "200")
```

Comment: `express` doesn't provide such functionality. You could use JS syntax like `req.query.someKey || 'default value'` for this or add another third party library

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to get page number param. So I used the ternary operator. The page number should be a positive number and if undefined or a string or is not a number or empty value should take a default value. 



     `const page =
      isNaN(req.query.page) ||
      req.query.page === undefined ||
      req.query.page == null ||
      Math.sign(Number(req.query.page)) <= 0 ||
      req.query.page.length <= 0
        ? 1
        : req.query.page;`

Comment: It looks overcomplicated. I suggest using schema validation libraries like joi or ajv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using schema validation libraries like [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) for query schema validation/transformation:

Example with [express-joi-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-joi-validation):

```
// ...
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');
const validator = require('express-joi-validation').createValidator({});

// ...

// If `page` is null, undefined, negative integer - set default value `0`
const querySchema = Joi.object({
  page: Joi.alternatives().try([
      Joi.number().integer().min(0),
      Joi.empty(Joi.any()).default(0),
  ])
});

// ...

router.get('/products', validator.query(querySchema), ProductController.getAllProducts);

// ...
```